# Informatica DEI 10.5.2 - Sqoop query importing data from Oracle 9i giving ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Tags: oracle, timezone, sqoop, informatica, ojdbc

Informatica mapping is giving error while extracting data using JDBC connection string connecting to Oracle 9.2 version. Informatica mapping is using Sqoop to execute the command.

I am executing the same command on EMR node and able to replicate the issue -Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

I tried lot of option to solve this issue, like adding parameters like below

Also tried using ojdbc6.jar version 11.1.0.7.0, 11.2.0.3.0(adding oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false in file oracle jdbc defaultConnectionProperties.properties), Ojdbc8.jar- 19.16.0.0.0

Command used: commented out the username, password and table

```
yarn jar ./sqoop-1.4.6-client.jar import -libjars /tmp/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar -Doracle.sessionTimeZone=GMT --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx:1526/xxxx --password xxxxx --username xxxx -m 1 --as-avrodatafile --mapreduce-job-name SPLIT_SET --query "SELECT * FROM SISADMIN.xxx WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --delete-target-dir --target-dir hdfs://ha-nn-uri//tmp/SPARK_infadmin/
```

Let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Is this because of Oracle 9.2 version or I need to add any other parameter in above statement. Please help

Thanks

Comment: added below parameters and tried but same error
-Doracle.sessionTimeZone=GMT
-Duser.timezone=GMT
-Dmapreduce.map.env=TZ=GMT
-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion='false'
-Duser.timezone=

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and blame the database version that has been out of support for 20 years. That said, you might also check here (http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2009/09/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found.html) for clues. Do you know for sure that your data contains a timestamp with a valid time zone specifier?

Comment: @pmdba - I am using simple statement - Select * from dual. this is also giving ORA-01882: timezone region not found. tried every possible solution on internet.
Current session NLS settings:
NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY = AMERICA
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY = AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = .,
NLS_CALENDAR = GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_TIME_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR